# How do I photograph a server room / datacenter floor in a unique way?

Tags: composition, product-photography, on-location

I have seen a lot of sys-admins and technical people who came here via StackOverflow or other Stackexchange sites and create stunning photography.
I would like to get input on creative angles and ways to shoot a *server room* and servers, that result in rather unique photography.
Google makes it seem so easy, but point and click shots usually turn out quite boring.

Comment: I understand what you are going for, but asking for a unique way to shoot a specific thing on a site like this is inherently ironic. You are going to need to add the uniqueness yourself, or it won't be individual. On the other hand, asking how to shoot a server room *is* a good question, since there are serious challenges around lighting, space, and so on. I suggest editing this to ask different things you can do to shoot a server room *well*, and then trying some of those to see what comes out to be the most interesting and unique from your point of view.

Answer (score 3):

I would give light painting a try.
Just put the camera on a tripod and color the corners of the room. or make some light stripes to show some abstract data flow of the servers.

Later on post processing you can blend different exposures/lightings together.

I have something like this in mind only in a server room.
http://photocritic.org/painting-with-light/

Answer (score 3):

Light the servers with colored gels, use a fast 50 mm f 1.4 lens and go for max bokeh on das blinkenlights on the front panel. Exaggerate the perspective of the server racks. Try high key lighting and shoot in B&W to go for a mid-60s IBM Big Blue era look (have the sysadmins dress like IBMers back in the day).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best idea - how about doing some scale stuff?

What I mean is - photographing servers modules from the bottom up as if they were skyscrapers? Must of been done 100 times though.

Just an idea!